# When to use Hibernate projections?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, nhibernate-projections

I am a little confused about Hibernate's *projections* and *criteria*. When to use projections and when to use criteria?

Comment: Think of projections like columns/summary you would like to present on a projector(so keywords like `min`/`max`/`avg`/`sum`/`count`/etc... comes into picture) // Think of criteria like a subset of the raw data(rows), possibly to confirm that a projection is correct (so keywords like `where`/`and`/etc... comes into picture. // Your manager: How did you come with this projection? You: Here are the criteria boss.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

They're not mutually exclusive, you can use both at the same time. Projections are generally used in the context of some Criteria.

To put it simple, Hibernate Projections are used in order to query only a subset of the attributes of an entity or group of entities you're querying with Criteria. You can also use Projections to specify `distinct` clauses and aggregate functions like `max`, `sum` and so on. It's like referring to **which** data you're fetching. Like modifying the `select` clause in an SQL query.

Hibernate Criteria are used to define conditions the data has to satisfy in order to be selected. It's like referring to **how** is the data you're fetching. Like modifiying the `from` and `where` clauses of an SQL query.

Note that this **how** and **which** is not strictly true, it's just an orientation aimed to aid the OP. You can change **which** data you're fetching with `createCriteria(String associationPath)` for instance.

I'd suggest to take a look at this article [Hibernate: Criteria Queries in Depth](https://web.archive.org/web/20160920104303/http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Hibernate-Criteria-Queries-in-Depth/)

Comment: And it is useful to count() as -> return (Number) session.createCriteria("Book").setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();

Comment: Well-said, thank you! I appreciated the comparison to SQL. That helped it "click" for me, as I have a little more background there.

Answer (score 6):

Projections are used to execute aggregate operations and to get single column query,with Restrictions we  can access a **ROW** but with PROJECTIONS we can access whole **COLUMN**

EX -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Student.class).buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
        Projection p = Projections.property("lastName");
        List<String> students = c.setProjection(p).list();
        for(String s:students)
            System.out.println(s);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    } finally {
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

In the above example i used projection call to ADD a projection property "name" to the criteria. It returns winchester winchester winchester winchester , which is the lastName **COLUMN** in the table.

Output =

> Hibernate: select this_.last_name as y0_ from student this_
>   winchester
>   winchester
>   winchester
>   winchester

Note - ***We can add only one projection, if we add more than 1 projection previous one will be overridden. if you want to add more than one projection you will nedd ProjectionList class***

Orignal Table -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate projections are useful for

1)Fetching only certain columns of the table

2)Performing aggregations like count,sum,max,min,avg.

Fetching only the columns which are needed **improves the performance** of the query.

Examples of projection

[Projections using DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719237/mapping-jpa-or-hibernate-projection-query-to-dto-data-transfer-object)

[Projection List example](https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate-projection-example.html)

Answer (score -1):

Projection is an Interface given in “org.hibernate.criterion” package, Projections is an class given in same package,  actually Projection is an interface, and Projections is an class and is a factory for producing projection objects.

In Projections class, we have all static methods and each method of this class returns Projection interface object.

If we want to add a Projection object to Criteria then we need to call a method setProjection()

Remember, while adding projection object to criteria, it is possible to add one object at a time.  It means if we add 2nd projection object then this 2nd one will overrides the first one (first one wont be work), so at a time we can only one projection object to criteria object

Using criteria, if we want to load partial object from the database, then we need to create a projection object for property that is to be loaded from the database

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Products.class);
crit.setProjection(Projections.proparty("proName"));
List l=crit.list();
Iterator it=l.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    String s = (String)it.next();
    // ---- print -----
}
```

If we add multiple projections to criteria then the last projection added will be considered to execute see…

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Products.class);

Projection p1 = Projection.property("proName");
Projection p2 = Projection.property("price");

crit.setProjection(p1):
crit.setProjection(p2):
List l=crit.list();
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: link to original http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/working-with-hibernate-projections-in-criteria/

Comment: Projection class does not have the property method.

Comment: Must be Projections instead of Projection. Mind the 's' at the end