# Mapping JPA or Hibernate projection query to DTO (Data Transfer Object)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, dozer

In my DAO layer, I have a Find function like this

```
public List<?> findCategoryWithSentenceNumber(int offset, int maxRec) {
  Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Category.class, "cate");
    crit.createAlias("cate.sentences", "sent");

    crit.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().
    add(Projections.property("title"), "title").
    add(Projections.count("sent.id"), "numberOfSentence").
    add(Projections.groupProperty("title"))
  );

  crit.setFirstResult(offset);
  crit.setMaxResults(maxRec);

  return crit.list();
}
```

So, in order to read the data, I have to use a Loop (with `Iterator`)

```
List<?> result = categoryDAO.findCategoryWithSentenceNumber(0, 10);
// List<DQCategoryDTO> dtoList = new ArrayList<>(); 

for (Iterator<?> it = result.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
  Object[] myResult = (Object[]) it.next();

  String  title = (String) myResult[0];
  Long count = (Long) myResult[1];


  assertEquals("test", title); 
  assertEquals(1, count.intValue()); 

  // dQCategoryDTO = new DQCategoryDTO();
  // dQCategoryDTO.setTitle(title);
  // dQCategoryDTO.setNumberOfSentence(count);
  // dtoList.add(dQCategoryDTO);

}
```

My question is: is there any api, framework to easily convert the `List<?> result` in to a list of `DTO` object (say, DQCategoryDTO) without using any loop, iterator and calling setter/getter to fill the value?

Comment: You can use resultTransformer which can convert from alias to bean (DTO) properties. Take look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628759/java-hibernate-criteria-setresulttransformertransformers-aliastobeanstudentm

Comment: @Shailendra: it works. Thank. Please make your comment as the answer :)

Comment: glad it helped ! I have added this as an answer !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) which can convert from alias to bean (DTO) properties. For usage you can refer to the Hibernate docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/) at section 13.1.5

Answer (score 42):

You have so many options for mapping your projection to a DTO result set:

### DTO projections using Tuple and JPQL

```
List<Tuple> postDTOs = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select
        p.id as id,
        p.title as title
    from Post p
    where p.createdOn > :fromTimestamp
    """, Tuple.class)
.setParameter( "fromTimestamp", Timestamp.from(
    LocalDateTime.of(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
        .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC )))
.getResultList();

assertFalse(postDTOs.isEmpty());
 
Tuple postDTO = postDTOs.get(0);
assertEquals( 
    1L, 
    postDTO.get("id") 
);
```

### DTO projections using a Constructor Expression and JPQL

```
List<PostDTO> postDTOs = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select new com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.query.dto.projection.jpa.PostDTO(
        p.id,
        p.title
    )
    from Post p
    where p.createdOn > :fromTimestamp
    """, PostDTO.class)
.setParameter( "fromTimestamp", Timestamp.from(
    LocalDateTime.of( 2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 )
        .toInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ))
.getResultList();
```

> You can also omit the DTO package name from the JPA constructor expression, and reference the DTO by its simple Java class name (e.g., [`PostDTO`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)).
>
> ```
> List<PostDTO> postDTOs = entityManager.createQuery("""
>     select new PostDTO(
>         p.id,
>         p.title
>     )
>     from Post p
>     where p.createdOn > :fromTimestamp
> ```

```
      """, PostDTO.class)
```

> ```
> .setParameter( "fromTimestamp", Timestamp.from(
>   LocalDateTime.of( 2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 )
>       .toInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ))
> .getResultList();
> ```

### DTO projections using Tuple and native SQL queries

This one is available from Hibernate 5.2.11 so yet one more reason to upgrade.

```
List<Tuple> postDTOs = entityManager.createNativeQuery("""
    SELECT
           p.id AS id,
           p.title AS title
    FROM Post p
    WHERE p.created_on > :fromTimestamp
    """, Tuple.class)
.setParameter( "fromTimestamp", Timestamp.from(
    LocalDateTime.of( 2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 )
        .toInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ))
.getResultList();
```

### DTO projections using a ConstructorResult

If we use the same `PostDTO` class type introduced previously, we have to provide the following `@SqlResultSetMapping`:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "PostDTO",
    query = """
        SELECT
               p.id AS id,
               p.title AS title
        FROM Post p
        WHERE p.created_on > :fromTimestamp
        """,
    resultSetMapping = "PostDTO"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "PostDTO",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = PostDTO.class,
        columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "id"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "title")
        }
    )
)
```

Now, the SQL projection named native query is executed as follows:

```
List<PostDTO> postDTOs = entityManager.createNamedQuery("PostDTO")
.setParameter( "fromTimestamp", Timestamp.from(
    LocalDateTime.of( 2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 )
        .toInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ))
.getResultList();
```

### DTO projections using ResultTransformer and JPQL

This time, your DTO requires to have the setters for the properties you need Hibernate to populate from the underlying JDBC `ResultSet`.

The DTO projection looks as follows:

```
List<PostDTO> postDTOs = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select
           p.id as id,
           p.title as title
    from Post p
    where p.createdOn > :fromTimestamp
    """)
.setParameter( "fromTimestamp", Timestamp.from(
    LocalDateTime.of( 2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ).toInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ))
.unwrap( org.hibernate.query.Query.class )
.setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean( PostDTO.class ) )
.getResultList();
```

### DTO projections using ResultTransformer and a Native SQL query

```
List postDTOs = entityManager.createNativeQuery("""
    select
           p.id as \"id\",
           p.title as \"title\"
    from Post p
    where p.created_on > :fromTimestamp
    """)
.setParameter( "fromTimestamp", Timestamp.from(
    LocalDateTime.of( 2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ).toInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ))
.unwrap( org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class )
.setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean( PostDTO.class ) )
.getResultList();
```

Comment: how can I use DTO projections using a ConstructorResult for Composite Object ?

Comment: thanks for the article, I'm following the same, but my DTO is complex, lets say `PostDTO` has list of `PostCommentDTO` as a field, In this case how can I Map  result to constructor ?

Comment: thanks for the example, but recursion is not my case, I'm finding it as hard to understand your query... (⌣̩̩́_⌣̩̩̀)

Comment: You can ignore the query and focus on the `ResultTransformer` which builds a hierarchy of DTOs.

Comment: sorry to bother you sir, but I'm stuck while returning result of `ResultTransformer`, for eg. I have 6 `Post`s, and total 12 `PostComment`s , I'm getting result as 12 `Post`s, with associated `PostComment`

Comment: Now working solved with the help of, `transformList` method

Comment: sir how to deal with returning single `Post` with all its `PostComment`s ?

Comment: `setResultTransformer` does not exists on the last example, neither the `NativeQuery.class`

Comment: [Yes it does](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/NativeQuery.html). It's inherited from [`org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#setResultTransformer-org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer-) base class.

Comment: would it be possible to create NamedNativeQuery and SqlResultSetMapping without any Entity or is required?

Comment: The @Target annotation says TYPE, so you need to add it to an Entity or MappedSuperclass.

Comment: How can I use "DTO projections using a Constructor Expressionand and JPQL"
when I have field-collection. For instance Set<Title> titles and relation One-to-Many between Post and Titles

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly the use case for which [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) has been created for!

Your DTO looks like

```
@EntityView(Category.class)
interface DQCategoryDTO  {
  String getTitle();
  @Mapping("SIZE(sentences)")
  int getCount();
}
```

and if you use Spring Data, you can use it in a repository like

```
interface CategoryRepository extends Repository<Category, Long> {
  List<DQCategoryDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is the complete example of how addresses are group together based on street name using Projection.

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Address.class);
// adding condition
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("zip", "12345"));
// adding projection
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.groupProperty("streetName"), "streetName")
.add(Projections.count("apartment"), "count"));
// set transformer
criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(SomeDTO.class));

List<SomeDTO> someDTOs = criteria.list();
```

> someDTOs list will contain number of result group by streetName. Each SomeDTO object contain street name and number of apartment in that street.

SomeDTO.java

```
public class SomeDTO{

private String streetName;
private Long count;

public void setStreetName(String streetName){
    this.streetName=streetName;
}
public String getStreetName(){
    return this.streetName;
}
public Long getCount() {
    return count;
}
public void setCount(Long count) {
    this.count = count;
}
}
```