# JPA merge table

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence, jparepository

I have table `employee`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="emp_id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="emp_name")
    private String empName;
    
    @Column(name="emp_mail")
    private String empMail;
    
    @Column(name="emp_no")
    private String empNo;

    @Column(name="emp_salary")
    private Long empSalary;
    
    @Column(name="type_id")
    private Long typeId;

}
```

In addition, I have table `employeetype` whose primary key type `id` is in employee table
[image]

How i am able to get response containg type_name not type_id in java data jpa for api using jparepository.
how to join table data.

Comment: If you want to get a record which does not exactly match an entity, you can build DTO class with the attributes you need and create a query with the syntax: 

    `select new DTO(e.a, e.b ...) from Entity e join ...`

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719237/mapping-jpa-or-hibernate-projection-query-to-dto-data-transfer-object

Comment: BTW, as you have an `employeetype` table, you can make a jpa entity `EmployeeType` out of it, and change the `typeId` on Employee to a `@ManyToOne` relation to `EmployeeType`. This design will help you building the query to get the type name of an employee.