# Spring data JPA from interface to impl in order to return a list of DTO's

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a query that works fine in the interface with the annotation @Query which looks like the following.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT  c.fecha, c.clave"
        + " FROM mavi.contrarecibo c "
        + " WHERE p.idproveedor = :idProveedor "
        + " AND c.fecha BETWEEN :inicio AND :termino "
        + " AND cf.estatusfactura = :estatusfactura"
        + " ORDER BY c.clave"
        ,
        nativeQuery = true
        )
List<ContrareciboPagoDto> pagosByProveedor(
        @Param("idProveedor")Long idProveedor,
        @Param("inicio")LocalDate inicio,
        @Param("termino")LocalDate termino,
        @Param("estatusfactura")String estatusContrareciboFacturaEnum
        );
```

This works fine, now in order to make this query more flexible I want to add some conditional restrictions, to do this I created an impl of this interface and tried the following.

//Only the method.

```
@Override
public List<ContrareciboPagoDto> pagosByProveedor(Long idProveedor, LocalDate inicio, LocalDate termino,
        String estatusContrareciboFacturaEnum) {
    
    StringBuilder qry = new StringBuilder("SELECT  c.fecha, c.clave, p.razonsocial, p.rfc, cf.numeroFactura, cf.monto, cf.fechaPago, oc.moneda, "
            + " pt.clabe, pt.cuentacontable, cf.uuid, p.diascredito, oc.descdepartamento, oc.observaciones, cf.estatusFactura "
            + " FROM mavi.contrarecibo c "
            + " JOIN mavi.contrarecibo_factura cf on cf.idcontrarecibo = c.idcontrarecibo "
            + " JOIN mavi.proveedor_tesoreria pt on pt.idproveedortesoreria = c.idproveedor "
            + " JOIN mavi.proveedor p on p.idproveedor = pt.idproveedor "
            + " JOIN mavi.orden_compra oc on oc.folio = cf.ordencompra "
            
            );
    
    if( idProveedor > 0) {
        qry.append(  " WHERE p.idproveedor = ").append(idProveedor);
    }

    // SOME OTHER RESTRICTIONS.
    
    return this.entityManager
                .createNativeQuery( qry.toString() , ContrareciboPagoDto.class)
                .getResultList();
}
```

ContrareciboPagoDto it is only an interface.

```
public interface ContrareciboPagoDto {
    

    public LocalDate getFechaRevision();

    public String getNumeroContraRecibo() ;
```

The problem with this is that I am getting an error.

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown entity:
> com.mavi.compras.service.dto.ContrareciboPagoDto; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:
> com.mavi.compras.service.dto.ContrareciboPagoDto

How can I implement this query to make it more versatile?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use DTO class with `createNativeQuery()` as it expects to receive a class annotated with `@Entity`. In order to get DTO you could use e.g. transformer:

```java
@Override
public List<ContrareciboPagoDto> pagosByProveedor(Long idProveedor, LocalDate inicio, LocalDate termino,
        String estatusContrareciboFacturaEnum) {
    
    StringBuilder qry = new StringBuilder("SELECT  c.fecha, c.clave, p.razonsocial, p.rfc, cf.numeroFactura, cf.monto, cf.fechaPago, oc.moneda, "
            + " pt.clabe, pt.cuentacontable, cf.uuid, p.diascredito, oc.descdepartamento, oc.observaciones, cf.estatusFactura "
            + " FROM mavi.contrarecibo c "
            + " JOIN mavi.contrarecibo_factura cf on cf.idcontrarecibo = c.idcontrarecibo "
            + " JOIN mavi.proveedor_tesoreria pt on pt.idproveedortesoreria = c.idproveedor "
            + " JOIN mavi.proveedor p on p.idproveedor = pt.idproveedor "
            + " JOIN mavi.orden_compra oc on oc.folio = cf.ordencompra "
            
            );
    
    if( idProveedor > 0) {
        qry.append(  " WHERE p.idproveedor = ").append(idProveedor);
    }

    // SOME OTHER RESTRICTIONS.
    
    return this.entityManager
                .createNativeQuery(qry.toString())
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ContrareciboPagoDto.class))
                .getResultList();
}
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45934668/12473843

Comment: It works fine, thank you. just a note.  In your answer it is missing this  `.unwrap( org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class )` after `.createNativeQuery(qry.toString())`